# Can I display compiler warnings in Sonar?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

Is there a way to include the Java compiler's warnings in SonarQube's analysis and dashboards?

I'm running SonarQube via Maven under Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this thread of discussion: http://sonar.15.x6.nabble.com/Java-compiler-warnings-Generics-td5015634.html