# Write the eclipse compiler errors as PMD rules for Sonar

Tags: eclipse, pmd, sonarqube

I want to track the eclipse compiler errors and warning in Sonar. However i'm surprised that most of them don't have a PMD equivalent.
It seems like a basic need to have the same errors tracked in sonar and in eclipse.

So just curious if someone already made a collection of rules for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I display compiler warnings in Sonar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364365/can-i-display-compiler-warnings-in-sonar)

Comment: This is along the same line indeed.
But for one the thread doesn't have an answer.
And i'm more looking at the same rules rewriten "à la" PMD than anything else.

Comment: This would be very hard to do, because PMD works on the *sources*, not the bytecode. So your first task would be to write a compiler. :-) However, do check other tools such as FindBugs, which works on the bytecode.

Comment: Yeah it's probably a mix of PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs rules.

Comment: What is the benefit of checking the style of not compiling code?